# Cross-device cookie tracking with Universal Analytics?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, universal-analytics, cross-device

Is it possible to set a cookie (for my domain) that is tied to a certain user across devices, somehow using the cross-device capabilities of Universal Analytics?

I don't need to know who that user is, just that it's the same person on a different device.

I know I can use Custom Dimensions (formerly Custom Variables) to assign an arbitrary value to a user/session but I need to be able to read it's value. It's a boolean value I need to store so even the fact it exists would be enough.

I hope I've explained clearly but if not let me know!

Comment: Just to see if I understand, you want to query in realtime Google Analytics to see if a current visitor on your site has previously visited you site on another device, and then you want to set a cookie based on the result ?

Comment: Kind of. Let's say some visits on mobile and selects their favourite colour as 'blue'. When they visit on desktop I want to know that this person (whoever they are) chose blue. But even knowing they chose anything is fine too.

Comment: Is it impolite to bump?